# Table columns widths are not equal

Tags: tables

I am trying two build a table, with the following code:

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{gamma function} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}zeta and gamma \\ function\end{tabular}} \\ \midrule
1          & 1         & 1         & 1                                          & 1                                         \\
2          & 3         & 4         & 5                                          & 6                                         \\
4          & 7         & 8         & 43                                         & 21                                        \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

But the third and fourth columns have different widths. I tried to set equal width for all columns, but doesn't work. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Do you want all five data columns to have the same width, or just columns 3 & 4?

Comment: I am trying to fix the same width for all columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution which sets all five columns to have equal width. It employs the `w` column type that's provided by the `array` package. The column contents are center-set via the `c` option in the first argument of the `w` columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}  % for "w" column type
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{@{} *{5}{w{c}{11mm} }@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{gamma function} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
   zeta and gamma \\ function\end{tabular}} \\ 
\midrule
1 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 1  \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 5  & 6  \\
4 & 7 & 8 & 43 & 21 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful! How I can add 6th column with different width?

Comment: @sane - change `*{5}{w{c}{11mm}}` to `*{5}{w{c}{11mm}}w{<some other width>}`.

Comment: Should I keep *{5}?

Comment: Ok, I tried the following *{5}{w{c}{11mm}}*{1}{w{c}{25mm}}. Itworks!

Comment: @sane - `*{1}{w{c}{25mm}}` and `w{c}{25mm}` have the exact same effect. The second expression avoids code clutter, though.

Answer (score 5):

I propose  this, with an empty column to separate the groups, `siunitx` and `makecell`  for the column heads:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\sisetup{table-format=2.0, table-number-alignment=center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}SSSc@{\enspace}SS}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{\thead{gamma \\ function}} & & \multicolumn{2}{@{\enspace}c}{\makebox[0pt]{\thead{zeta and\\ gamma \\ functions}}} \\
\midrule
1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & & 5 & 6 \\
4 & 7 & 8 & & 43 & 21 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many many wishes for your reputation of 200k: auguriiiiiiiiiiiiiii !

Comment: Mille grazie!!!